# the sum of Big decimal values should be equal after division in java

Tags: java

I have 6 `BigDecimals`, let say

`a,b,c,d,e,f and tot`
The sum of all these values(`a,b,c,d,e,f`) are equal to `tot`
I am calculating average and storing in other variable of type BigDecimal, just say `avgA, avgB, avgC, avgD, avgE, avgF and avgTot`. now if I add all these

```
avgA, avgB, avgC, avgD, avgE, avgF
```

this sum should be equal to `avgTot`

But sum of all the averages(`avgA, avgB, avgC, avgD, avgE, avgF`) is not equal to `totAvg`

here is sample code

```
BigDecimal avgA = a.divide(new BigDecimal(counter), 15,RoundingMode.CEILING);
BigDecimal avgB = b.divide(new BigDecimal(counter), 15,RoundingMode.CEILING);
BigDecimal avgTot = tot.divide(new BigDecimal(counter), 15,RoundingMode.CEILING);

BigDecimal trimA = avgA.setScale(4, RoundingMode.CEILING);
BigDecimal trimB = avgB.setScale(4, RoundingMode.CEILING);
BigDecimal trimTot = avgTot.setScale(4, RoundingMode.CEILING);
```

Sample Values:-

```
trimA 0.0004
trimB 0.0000
trimC 0.0022
trimD 0.0047
trimE 0.0000
trimF 0.0002
trimTot 0.0076
```

The problem is `sum(TrimA..F)` is not equal to `trimTot`. I have to make sure that `sum(TrimA..F)` should be equal to `trimTot`

Comment: post some code, of what have you done ? and what error are you getting?

Comment: Okay. And your question is what exactly?

Comment: I am getting difference with the sum of all and totAvg

Comment: What do you store in your BigDecimal? floats, integers, doubles? I am guessing it's not integers....

Comment: those are double values

Comment: What are those avgA, avgB .. and how do you calculate them?

Comment: I jsu edited question and added code also

Comment: `avgTot` should be divided by the *total counter* which is the sum of all counters, which equals (counter for `avgA` + counter for `avgB` + ...).

Comment: You couldn't explain what you did and what you want clearly. I'm going to talk based only on the output for this reason. I probably misunderstand your intention. Assuming your problem is that sum(trimA..F) isn't equal to trimTot. Sum of trims is 0.0075 but trimTot is 0.0076. It's an undesirable effect that is called as loss of significance. You're working with finite-precision arithmetic and it's inevitable if you set insufficient scale. To exemplify, 0.5 + 0.25 = 0.75 but if for all numbers the scale is 1, the calculation becomes 0.5 + 0.2 = 0.7.

Comment: The problem is sum(TrimA..F) is not equal to `trimTot`. I have to make sure that sum(TrimA..F) should be equal to `trimTot`

Comment: @SathishKumar They aren't `double` values. They're `BigDecimal' values which represent numbers as arbitrary precision decimals and very different from floating point (which `double` is an example). If anything `double` is even more prone to these rounding issues and it's quite common that assigning C=A+B and then calculating D=C-B doesn't result in D=A. That is the sum not being the exact sum of its parts.

Answer (score 0):

The devious thing is that `RoundingMode.CEILING` ensures a maximal error on addition instead of `RoundingMode.HALF_UP`:

CEILING

```
0.00031 => 0.0004
0.00211 => 0.0022
-------    ------ +
0.00242    0.0026
```

HALF_UP (the norm)

```
0.00033 => 0.0003
0.00216 => 0.0022
-------    ------ +
0.00249    0.0025
```

FLOOR

```
0.00043 => 0.0004
0.00216 => 0.0021
-------    ------ +
0.00259    0.0025
```

So

```
BigDecimal trimA = avgA.setScale(4, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
BigDecimal trimB = avgB.setScale(4, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
BigDecimal trimTot = avgTot.setScale(4, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

would minimize the rounding error, but not necessarily always remove it.

So what do you think, to have no rounding upto the 4th decimal. When going from 15 positions to 4.

Answer (score 0):

It simply isn't the case for any rounding method that in general Round(A+B) = Round(A)+Round(B).

People bodge these problems at a high level of precision to minimize the incidence of visible rounding errors but that often doesn't work entirely. 
Note: Joop Eggen has just posted such an answer. Please note I'm not using 'bodge' in a judgmental sense!

Without providing an explanation of why an impossible constraint is required it's difficult to give useful advice.

One obvious way is to *define* the average for A, B, C as A/3+B/3+C/3.
Another approach is to work through a calculation as rational numbers.
That means either keeping track of the numerator and denominator or using a specialised `Rational class`.